# Workaround for poor C++ behavior in Intel 13.1.2 with deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm stuck supporting back to Intel 13.1.2, which is nominally C++11 compliant, but this code:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct moveonly {
  moveonly()                =default;
  moveonly(const moveonly&) =delete;
  moveonly(moveonly&& other) { member = std::move(other.member); }

private:
  int member = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct holds {
  operator T&&() { return std::move(t); }
  T t;
};


int main() {
  holds<moveonly> m;
  moveonly a = m;
}
```

Fails to compile:

```
 ╰─▸ icc -std=c++11 test.cc -o test
test.cc(21): error: function "moveonly::moveonly(const moveonly &)" (declared at line 5) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
    moveonly a = m;
                 ^

test.cc(21): error: function "moveonly::moveonly(const moveonly &)" (declared at line 5) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
    moveonly a = m;
                 ^

compilation aborted for test.cc (code 2)
```

Assuming I can't make the class copyable, and would like to keep the conversion operator, can anyone come up with a workaround?

Comment: Intel 13 was never C++11. They may have said something like that, but this was wishful thinking.

Comment: @Walter seriously...

Comment: yes? I am serious. I gave up on Intel compilers for any C++ standard less then 5 years old....

Comment: Sorry, the tone got lost, I was agreeing with you, it's awful but I'm stuck with it for now =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to make the rvalue explicit:

```
moveonly a = std::move(m);
```

Possibly, explicit cast helps as well:

```
moveonly a = static_cast<moveonly&&>(m);
```

Calling the cast operator explicitly:

```
moveonly a = m.operator moveonly&&();
```

If all fails, falling back to pre-C++11 means:

```
struct holds
{
    operator T&&() { return std::move(t); }
    T t;
    swap(T& tt)
    {
        swap(t, tt);
    }
};
```

with appropriate swap defined for moveonly, so you could:

```
moveonly a;
m.swap(a);
```

Comment: But I have an rvalue reference through my conversion operator (note this compiles fine on gcc).  In any event, std::move(m) generates the same error.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister,  this answer, it if works, satisfies your request: it would be a work around and you can avoid allowing copies but keep the conversion. I'm surprised about the futile downvote.

Comment: Unfortunately neither works, the static_cast generates an invalid type conversion error.   I guess I'm stuck with an explicit member function ::value() in the non-copyable case.

Comment: Wording might have been better... Adjusted, plus added some further options.